# MySQL query suggestion needed

Tags: mysql, select-query

I have three tables: Orders, OrderAdditionalInfo, Invoices

I need to select (main) orders that has no valid (or uncancelled) invoice.

Fields:

Orders ->

```
OrderID int(11)
```

OrderAdditionalInfo ->

```
DetailID int(11)
OrderID int(11)
Variable varchar(255)
Value varchar(255)
```

Invoices ->

```
InvoiceID int(11)
OrderID int(11)
Cancelled tinyint(4) //if cancelled is 1 then this invoice is invalid.
```

*IMPORTANT:*
The thing that confuses everything is:
One order can be divided into multiple orders.

For example:

When we divide an order with an OrderID: 10

1- Order 10 remains as the main order and a new order with ID 11 is added to the table. (We gain a new order.)

2- Unfortunately, a row is added to OrderAdditionalInfo table:

```
OrderID: 11
Variable: "Main Order ID"
Value: "10"
```

3- So, we can know the order 11 has been derivered from order 10.

Do you have any suggestions about selecting orders that matches:

*"main order"* (is not derivered from another order)

and

*"has no valid invoice"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from orders o where o.OrderId not in (select OrderId from Invoices) and o.OrderId not in (select OrderId from OrderAdditionalInfo oi where oi.Variable = 'Main Order ID')
```